# Mongodb java driver connection time outs

Tags: mongodb, sockets, mongodb-java

I did a fresh install of mongoDB (3.4.5) on my Ubuntu 16.04.

I am able to successfully connect with the python driver, however my java driver keeps returning a connection timed out exception.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:?]
... 3 more
```

I have started mongo DB with the following config options:

```
{ config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", port: 27017 }, 
storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } },
 systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log", quiet: true } }
```

And in my Java class, I have:

`MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(host:"0.0.0.0", port:27017);`

I have checked using telnet that port 27017 is accessible. Not sure why else this is causing a connection timed out. I'll really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the [documentation page for `MongoClient()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html). You are not passing valid arguments. Should be `new MongoClient("0.0.0.0",27017)` or even just `new MongoClient("0.0.0.0")` since `27017` is the default port and will be used anyway.

Comment: Oh, new MongoClient("0.0.0.0",27017) is how I passed it. My editor has been set to show me argument names, hence the 'host' and 'port' shows up like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some issues regarding the outgoing port 27017 being blocked. Adding a firewall rule to open that port fixed the issue.

Comment: was the outbound port required to be opened on mongo db server?